# How to disable previous month navigation arrow in react-calender?

Tags: reactjs, react-calendar

I am new to react and I am Using the react-calender package, I want to disable the previous month's navigation arrow if selected month in react-calender and current month is same.
Ex.If any one go to next to next month i.e.May and currently ongoing month is march then I don't want to disable previous month navigation arrow.

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can override css

```
.react-calendar__navigation__prev-button {
    opacity: 0.5;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing **null** to **prev2Label** and **next2Label** prop will hide options for year navigation

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).